# Create array data structure from nested object of arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data structure as follows:

***UPDATED: to have more than one object in innerValues***

```
 const data = {
  "dates": [
    "2015-09-09T00:00:00",
    "2015-09-09T00:10:00",
    "2015-09-09T00:20:00",
  ],
  "innerValues": [
    {
    "name": "Name_1",
    "value": [
      104,
      105,
      107,
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Name_2",
    "value": [
      656,
      777,
      145,
    ]
  }],
}
```

I would like to create an output like:

```
const outPut = [
   ["2015-09-09T00:00:00", 'Name_1', 104 ],
   ["2015-09-09T00:10:00", 'Name_1', 105 ],
   ["2015-09-09T00:20:00", 'Name_1', 107 ],
   ["2015-09-09T00:00:00", 'Name_2', 104 ],
   ["2015-09-09T00:10:00", 'Name_2', 105 ],
   ["2015-09-09T00:20:00", 'Name_2', 107 ]
]
```

So far I have this, I know I could do this with forEach etc also - but as an example.

```
const m = data.dates;
let arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Array(m[i]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

This gives:

```
0: ['2021-09-09T00:00:00']
1: ['2021-09-09T00:10:00']
2: ['2021-09-09T00:20:00']
```

Which is where I want to start, however if I map over `inner.values` and try to create an new array from that, it does not return three separate arrays but one.e.g

```
const newArray = x.forEach(inner => console.log(new Array(inner)))
```

Output

```
0: (3) [104, 105, 107]
```

How could I achieve the above desired structure.

Comment: Think about your for loop... you have the index available to access both `data.dates` and `innerValues[0].value` (hint: `[data.dates[0], innerValues[0].name, innerValues[0].value[0]]`)

Comment: Can't you have the endpoint (I'm assuming) that's giving you that data output it in the correct format?

Comment: @Andy yes, although this is for a specific component which could change in the future, so to not change the api in the first instance.

Comment: @pilchard can you elaborate? that would be accessing the first element i.e `[0]` but how would I get each value and associate it to the Name_1 property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce and map to loop over innerValues and their values

```js
const dates = data.dates
const newArr = data.innerValues.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  acc.push(cur.value.map((value, i) => ([dates[i], cur.name, value])));
  return acc;
}, []).flat()
console.log(newArr)
```

```html
<script>
  const data = {
    "dates": [
      "2015-09-09T00:00:00",
      "2015-09-09T00:10:00",
      "2015-09-09T00:20:00",
    ],
    "innerValues": [{
        "name": "Name_1",
        "value": [
          104,
          105,
          107,
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Name_2",
        "value": [
          656,
          777,
          145,
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for example say if there was another object in innerValues, would it work the same way? i.e 'Name_2'

Comment: I have updated the question, with example

Comment: @Sole Push is more elegant

Comment: Could this use concat instead of flat?